# Please comment on this use-case for accessing the Lucene API directly from the context of a Neo4j User Defined Procedure

Tags: neo4j

I would like to build an in-memory Lucene index from a collection of node properties and then search against that index.

These search transactions will be happening in parallel, I need to be able to construct a separate search index for each transaction. It seems like this would not be possible using native (manual) Neo4j indexes, since they are "global", hence the use of a memory-based search index, am I mistaken?

Comment: That is probably possible ... but why bother ? You can add and destroy manual indexes at will. The APOC procedures are ideal for that : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_text_and_lookup_indexes

Comment: I want to avoid the cost of building indexes graph-wide, the graph could potentially contain millions of nodes.  This operation needs to complete quickly.  Would not the temporary, manual indexes apply to all nodes, graph-wide?

Comment: Check the APOC procedures. I believe you can add only the nodes that you want (apoc.index.addNode would indicate that) in the index.

Comment: Many of these micro-search transactions will be happening in parallel, I need to be able to construct a separate search index for each transaction. It seems like this would not be possible using native (manual) Neo4j indexes, since they are "global", hence the use of a memory-based search index, am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working great for our use case.  A couple of notes:

1. Use MemoryIndex rather than RAMDirectory.
2. Be sure to specify "provided" in your dependencies for Lucene.
3. You can only use 5.5.0, which is what is used natively by Neo4j.